# Is there a way to extract a solid box slice of an arbitrary multidimensional Python array given two sets of corner index coordinates?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy-slicing, array-indexing

Suppose I have `a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)`, which is

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

And want to slice `a` as I could with `a[0:3,1:4]`, which results in

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

using the supplied coordinates, [(0,1), (2,3)], which are the indexes of the corners of that box slice.

I'd like to make a function that takes any n-dimensional array and two sets of index coordinates like this and slices the array between these two coordinates, inclusive.
(Maybe to be Pythonic, I would not include the last index, so the previously mentioned index coordinates would be [(0,1), (3,4)]. This detail isn't important.)

An example:

```
import numpy as np

def box_slice(array, start, stop):
    # will return slice
    pass

a = np.arange(3*5*6).reshape(3,5,6)
```

`a` is now

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]],

       [[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
        [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
        [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
        [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]],

       [[60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65],
        [66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
        [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77],
        [78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83],
        [84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]]])
```

This should be equivalent to `a[0:3, 1:4, 2:5]`, assuming the Pythonic implementation:

```
box_slice(a, [0,1,2], [3,4,5])
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 8,  9, 10],
        [14, 15, 16],
        [20, 21, 22]],

       [[38, 39, 40],
        [44, 45, 46],
        [50, 51, 52]],

       [[68, 69, 70],
        [74, 75, 76],
        [80, 81, 82]]])
```

This could be achieved with `eval()`, but I don't want to follow that approach unless I have to. Is there already a function that can achieve this with minimal manipulation of the inputs? I prefer NumPy usage, but solutions using other libraries or raw Python are also encouraged.

The solution needs to support any number of dimensions without modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about a numpy way of doing this but you can use `slice` and `zip` to do this.

```
import numpy as np

def box_slice(arr, start, stop):
    return arr[tuple(slice(*i) for i in zip(start, stop))]

a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
print(box_slice(a, [0, 1], [3, 4]))

a = np.arange(3 * 5 * 6).reshape(3, 5, 6)
print(box_slice(a, [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]))
```

Output

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 5  6  7]
 [ 9 10 11]]



[[[ 8  9 10]
  [14 15 16]
  [20 21 22]]

 [[38 39 40]
  [44 45 46]
  [50 51 52]]

 [[68 69 70]
  [74 75 76]
  [80 81 82]]]
```